# Natural deduction Tree Proof

Tags: proof-verification

I'm working on this:
$$\dashv \lnot P \to \ (( P \to\ \lnot Q)\to\lnot P)  $$

So I did this :

$1\     assume \ \lnot p.\\
2 \     assume \ p \to \lnot q.\\
3 \     therefore \ (p \to \lnot q)\to \lnot p.  \ (\to)I 2,1\\
4 \   therefore \ \lnot p \to \ (p \to \lnot q)\to \lnot p.                      (\to)I 1,3$

And now tree proof,is it good?

\begin{align}
\cfrac{\cfrac {\cfrac{[\lnot p]^1}{[p\to \lnot q]^1} }{(p\to\lnot q )\to \lnot p } (\to)\text {I}}
{\lnot p \to((p\to\lnot q )\to \lnot p)} (\to) \text {I}
\end{align}

Comment: Start with $\neg p$ on top

Comment: @Bram28 ok it was my error, but it is right?

Comment: OK, I still don;t know the exact rules, but looking at it intuitively, I would think that since $p \to \neg q$ is an assumption, that that should not go under the $\neg p$, but rather to the side of it. Then when you do the first $\to I$, you 'use' the $p \to \neg q$ (so that gets index 1), and when you do the second $\to I$, you use the $\neg p$ (so that should get a 2.  And maybe use these indices also with the rules so you know what goes with what.

Comment: I put how I think it is in my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So more like this ...

\begin{align}
\cfrac{\cfrac {[\lnot p]^2 \: [p\to \lnot q]^1 }{(p\to\lnot q )\to \lnot p } (\to)\text {I}^1}
{\lnot p \to((p\to\lnot q )\to \lnot p)} (\to) \text {I}^2
\end{align}